# Admissions rate using UCBAdmissions data set in R

Tags: r

`ftable(round(proportions(UCBAdmissions,c(2,3))*100, 1),row.vars=c(2, 1),col.vars=3)`

[image: ftable(round(proportions(UCBAdmissions,c(2,3))*100, 1),row.vars=c(2, 1),col.vars=3)]

I've managed to do this far but I just cannot think of a way to delete the "Rejected" rows so that only "Admitted" proportions can be displayed. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn it into a tibble and then filter with `dplyr`:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Save Table as Object ####
admissions <- ftable(round(proportions(UCBAdmissions, c(2, 3)) * 100, 1),
       row.vars = c(2, 1),
       col.vars = 3)

#### Convert to Tibble and Filter ####
admissions %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  filter(!Admit == "Rejected")
```

Giving you this:

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
   Gender Admit    Dept   Freq
   <fct>  <fct>    <fct> <dbl>
 1 Male   Admitted A      62.1
 2 Female Admitted A      82.4
 3 Male   Admitted B      63  
 4 Female Admitted B      68  
 5 Male   Admitted C      36.9
 6 Female Admitted C      34.1
 7 Male   Admitted D      33.1
 8 Female Admitted D      34.9
 9 Male   Admitted E      27.7
10 Female Admitted E      23.9
11 Male   Admitted F       5.9
12 Female Admitted F       7
```